# latex fancyhdr: is possible to use leftmark and rightmark alternatively?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using this code to customize the header layout:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\rhead{\thepage}
```

I would like to have the section name in the top left of every page, in the form of “1.1 section”, and this is possible using \rightmark. But, like mentioned in the fancyhdr documentation, "on the ﬁrst page of a chapter (or a section in article style) the \rightmark will be empty". So, when \rightmark is empty I would like have printed the chapter name like “Chapter 1. Intro” instead of the section name, and this is possible using \leftmark. So my question is: can I use such an "else condition" in order to use \leftmark if \rightmark is empty, and to use \rightmark otherwise? Something like:

```
empty(\rightmark) ? \leftmark : \rightmark
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can test if the `\rightmark` is empty by fully expanding it; the command `\rightorleftmark` will do what you want (uncomment the `\section` line to see the difference).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\rightorleftmark}}
\rhead{\thepage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rightorleftmark}{%
  \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\rightmark}%
  \ifx\x\@empty
    \endgroup\leftmark
  \else
    \endgroup\rightmark
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A}
%\section{B}
abc\newpage
def\newpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved with these commands, they print the chapter name and number on odd page, and the section on even.
When there is no section defined yet for even page, it prints again the chapter name and number.

```
\newcommand{\customizedheader}{
    \ifthenelse
         {\isodd{\thepage}}
         {\leftmark{}}
         {\checkemptyrightmark{\rightmark{}}}
}

\newcommand{\checkemptyrightmark}[1]{
    \ifthenelse
        {\equal{#1}{\@empty{}}}
        {\leftmark{}}
        {\rightmark}
}
```

And finally use the macro for the header

```
\newcommand{\currentPar}{\customizedheader}
```

Ah, the ifthenelse command come from the ***ifthen*** package and the \@empty is defined as

```
\def\@empty{}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please rewrite your code as a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) such everybody can apply your answer successfully.