# How to hide customized header on section start

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr

This question is directly related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187853/49121) one.
I used the code and wanted to have an empty pagestyle on pages having a section start and at the same time the header should be customized like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101926/49121) one.
When I use the codes together it won't work anymore, because the title in the header is now the title from the table of contents.

When a section starts there is no header:

[image: first]

When a section starts and has another [sub]section in it there should be a header but is not.

[image: second]

When there is no section at the page the header should have the rightmark if it's not blank, else the leftmark. That worked before merging the codes, now it doesn't (in this example it should be the current section):

[image: third]

Here are some cases for what should be inside the header and when there should be a header:

- If the page starts with a section and has no previous text that breaked to the page there shouldn't be a header.
- If there is text that breaks to the page from a [*]section there should be a header containing the number and title of [*].
- If the page doesn't has breaking text and starts with a sub[*]section it should have a header and in the header the number and title of the upper section e.g. if the page starts a subsection it should hold the section title.

How can I get both working, no header at section start and a customized header on pages, which don't have a section start *or* have [sub]sections which break to this page?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            ngerman}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=4cm,
    right=3cm,
    top=3cm,
    bottom=3cm,
    %showframe,
    headheight=15pt,
    includeheadfoot
]{geometry}
\linespread{1.25}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xparse}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\rightorleftmark}}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{section}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187853/49121
\let\originalsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsection*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\originalsection{#3}}
      {\originalsection[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
  \thispagestyle{section}%
}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101926/49121
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rightorleftmark}{%
  \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\rightmark}%
  \ifx\x\@empty
    \endgroup\leftmark
  \else
    \endgroup\rightmark
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \setcounter{page}{1} % when using custom titlepage

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pdfbookmark{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{tableofcontents}
  \markboth{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{}
  \tableofcontents

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pdfbookmark{Abbildungsverzeichnis}{listoffigures}
  \listoffigures

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pdfbookmark{Tabellenverzeichnis}{listoftables}
  \listoftables


  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \cleardoublepage
  \blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you never set the `\rightmark`, obviously the last set one (that is, the TOC title) is used.

Comment: I didn't set it before, too. But it worked before.

Comment: I'm not sure it does what you want, but adding `\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}` (or variant thereof if you need the number) should do.

Comment: Thanks that's the right direction. But I want the [sub]section title from the previous page not from the current. So the reader of the breaking block knows what was the title of it.

Comment: Now there are all cases IMO. Thanks for having a look I will put some bounty on this asap.

Comment: Did you think of using `titleps` (a component of `\titlesec`) in the place of `fancyhdr`? It doesn't require using marks.

Comment: Yes I tried using it but for me the manual is too hard to understand, there are no visual examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for the real original problem, including the third requirement (text header of next higher (*)section command if the page starts with a sub(*)section. I don't know if it covers all corner cases, but the normal cases seem to work well. I have put this as a separate answer because both address slightly different problems.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            ngerman}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=4cm,
    right=3cm,
    top=3cm,
    bottom=2.9cm,
    %showframe,
    headheight=15pt,
    includeheadfoot
]{geometry}
\linespread{1.25}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} % give \pagestyle{fancy} here to initialize fancyhdr.
\fancyhf{}

% We are going to use \rightmark for the section or subsection title to be
% placed in the header and \firstleftmark (from the extramarks package)
% to indicate where it comes from:
% prev = from a (sub)section on the previous page
% newpage = from a \newpage command 
% section = from a \section command on this page
% subsection = from a \subsection command on this page
% We use \firstleftmark because the normal \leftmark gives us the LAST
% left mark on the page instead of the first one.
%
% Our solution is to issue a \markboth command with "prev" as left part
% before each \(sub)section command. This serves two purposes:
% (1) In this way the previous (sub)section title will be used in the header.
% (2) When the pagebreak comes just before the \section command, the
% previous page will have a "prev" (last) \leftmark and the current page
% will have a "section" \firstleftmark. This combination determines that
% there is a section at the top of the page.
% In order to work properly, \newpage must also issue such a mark. In
% that case we put "newpage" in the leftmark, but that information is
% currently not used.

% Test if there is a section at the top of the page.

\newcommand{\iftopsection}[2]{% %1 = true action, #2 = false action
     \ifthenelse{\equal{\firstleftmark}{section}}{#1}{#2}}

% If there is a section on top of the page, suppress the header
% If it is a subsection, use the last section title (in \firstleftxmark)
% If it is a subsubsection, use the last subsection title (in \firstrightxmark).
% Otherwise we have overflow from the previous page and we use \rightmark
% (which should be the current (*)section from \prevmark).

\lhead{\nouppercase{%
     \iftopsection{}
       {\ifthenelse{\equal{\firstleftmark}{subsection}}
         {\firstleftxmark}%
         {\ifthenelse{\equal{\firstleftmark}{subsubsection}}
           {\firstrightxmark}{\rightmark}}}}}

%% \rhead{\firstleftmark} % This is for debugging!!!!!
\cfoot{\thepage}

% If there is a \section command on the top of the page, make \headrule empty.

\let\originalheadrule\headrule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
     \iftopsection{}{\originalheadrule}}

% Define the format the (*)section titles have in the header

\newcommand{\secTH}[1]{\thesection\quad #1}
\newcommand{\subsecTH}[1]{\thesubsection\quad #1}
\newcommand{\subsubsecTH}[1]{\thesubsubsection\quad #1}

% Mark commands for the (*)sections. We set the title in the rightmark,
% and also keep the extramarks current (last section and subsection title).

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{section}{\secTH{#1}}%
   \extramarks{\secTH{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markboth{subsection}{\subsecTH{#1}}%
  \extramarks{\prevsection}{\subsecTH{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markboth{subsubsection}{\subsubsecTH{#1}}}

% We remember the title of the previous (*)section in \prevmark.
% We have also commands to remember the last section and subsection
% titles specifically. We will remember these with \extramarks.

\newcommand{\prevmark}{}
\newcommand{\prevsection}{}
\newcommand{\prevsubsection}{}

% This inserts the \prevmark as a mark before the (sub)section command.
% There is a \nopagebreak before it, so that (hopefully) it will stick
% with the previous text. So we hope the page will be broken after it if necessary.
% And then we set the new \prevmark value to the (sub)section title.
% We set the last section and subsection titles with \extramarks.

\newcommand{\insertprevmark}[1]{%
  \nopagebreak
  \ifx\prevmark\empty\else\markboth{prev}{\prevmark}%
  \extramarks{\prevsection}{\prevsubsection}\fi
  \renewcommand{\prevmark}{#1}%
}

% Change \section so that it will insert a "prev" mark first. 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187853/49121
\let\originalsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \insertprevmark{\secTH{#3}}%
  \renewcommand{\prevsection}{\secTH{#3}}%
  \renewcommand{\prevsubsection}{}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsection*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\originalsection{#3}}
      {\originalsection[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}

% Change \subsection so that it will insert a "prev" mark first. 
\let\originalsubsection\subsection
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{som}{%
  \insertprevmark{\subsecTH{#3}}%
  \renewcommand{\prevsubsection}{\subsecTH{#3}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsubsection*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\originalsubsection{#3}}
      {\originalsubsection[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}

% Change \subsubsection so that it will insert a "prev" mark first. 
\let\originalsubsubsection\subsubsection
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsubsection}{som}{%
  \insertprevmark{\subsubsecTH{#3}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsubsubsection*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\originalsubsubsection{#3}}
      {\originalsubsubsection[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}

% adapt \newpage so that it issues a "prev" mark, and makes \prevmark empty

\let\originalnewpage\newpage
\renewcommand{\newpage}{\markboth{newpage}{\prevmark}\global\let\prevmark\empty\originalnewpage}

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \setcounter{page}{1} % when using custom titlepage

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pdfbookmark{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{tableofcontents}
  \markboth{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{}
  \tableofcontents

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pdfbookmark{Abbildungsverzeichnis}{listoffigures}
  \listoffigures

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pdfbookmark{Tabellenverzeichnis}{listoftables}
  \listoftables

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \section{This is a test section}
  \blindtext
  \subsection{This is a subsection}
  \blindtext
  \section{This is another section}


This is some text.   This is some text.   This is some text.   
This is some text.   This is some text.   This is some text.   
This is some text.   This is some text.   This is some text.   
This is some text.   This is some text.   This is some text.   

\subsection{This is another subsection}

  Some more text. 

 \cleardoublepage
  \blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's nearly perfect! One thing that I see that doesn't work is if you put some `\blindtext` commands (like 5) in a sequence after the `\blinddocument` then there is text filling the complete page, belonging to the same section. But it differs in it's header titles.

Comment: The empty line is still there, where should be no header. I try to find out what is the problem, maybe some other package I use.

Comment: I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

**Original answer:**
Instead of testing if the `\rightmark` is empty and then choosing `\leftmark` it is much easier to make sure that when the `\leftmark` is set, also the `\rightmark` is set to the same value.

This can be done with:

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection. #1}{\thesection. #1}}
```

and the you can just use `\rightmark`:

```
\lhead{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
```

**Edit: Below I have added what I think is a complete solution to the original problem.**

**Change Note Dec 20,2016:** I have replaced the solution with a simpler one, that does not need `\topmark`. I think it is more robust.

However the OP brought to my attention that it doesn't satisfy the third requirement:

- If the page doesn't has breaking text and starts with a sub[*]section it should have a header and in the header the number and title of the upper section e.g. if the page starts a subsection it should hold the section title.

Instead on a page that starts with a sub[*]section it uses the title of that sub[*]section in the header. I am working to find a solution to the other requirement.

Now here is a solution to the original (complicated) problem. It's quite some trickery with marks, and I hope I have covered all the corner cases. Explanation is in the comments.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            ngerman}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=4cm,
    right=3cm,
    top=3cm,
    bottom=3cm,
    %showframe,
    headheight=15pt,
    includeheadfoot
]{geometry}
\linespread{1.25}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} % give \pagestyle{fancy} here to initialize fancyhdr.
\fancyhf{}

% We are going to use \rightmark for the section or subsection title to be
% placed in the header and \firstleftmark (from the extramarks package)
% to indicate where it comes from:
% prev = from a (sub)section on the previous page
% section = from a \section command on this page
% subsection = from a \subsection command on this page
% We use \firstleftmark because the normal \leftmark gives us the LAST
% left mark on the page instead of the first one.
%
% Our solution is to issue a \markboth command with "prev" as left part
% before each \(sub)section command. This serves two purposes:
% (1) In this way the previous (sub)section title will be used in the header.
% (2) When the pagebreak comes just before the \section command, the
% previous page will have a "prev" (last) \leftmark and the current page
% will have a "section" \firstleftmark. This combination determines that
% there is a section at the top of the page. In order to work properly,
% a \newpage must also issue such a mark.

% If there is a section command at the top, don't put a header (put an
% empty header)

% Test if there is a section at the top of the page.

\newcommand{\iftopsection}[2]{% %1 = true action, #2 = false action
     \ifthenelse{\equal{\firstleftmark}{section}}{#1}{#2}}

\lhead{\nouppercase{%
     \iftopsection{}{\rightmark}}}
%\rhead{\firstleftmark} % This is for debugging!!!!!
\cfoot{\thepage}

% If there is a \section command on the top of the page, make \headrule empty.

\let\originalheadrule\headrule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
     \iftopsection{}{\originalheadrule}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{section}{\thesection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markboth{subsection}{\thesubsection\ #1}}

% We remember the title of the previous (sub)section in \prevmark.

\newcommand{\prevmark}{}
% This inserts the \prevmark as a mark before the (sub)section command.
% There is a \nopagebreak before it, so that (hopefully) it will stick
% with the previous text. So we hope the page will be broken after it if necessary.
% And then we set the new \prevmark value to the (sub)section title.

\newcommand{\insertprevmark}[1]{%
  \nopagebreak
  \ifx\prevmark\empty\else\markboth{prev}{\prevmark}\fi
  \renewcommand{\prevmark}{#1}%
}

% Change \section so that it will insert a "prev" mark first. 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187853/49121
\let\originalsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \insertprevmark{\thesection\ #3}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsection*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\originalsection{#3}}
      {\originalsection[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}

% Change \subsection so that it will insert a "prev" mark first. 
\let\originalsubsection\subsection
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{som}{%
  \insertprevmark{\thesubsection\ #3}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsubsection*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\originalsubsection{#3}}
      {\originalsubsection[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}

% Change \subsubsection so that it will insert a "prev" mark first. 
\let\originalsubsubsection\subsubsection
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsubsection}{som}{%
  \insertprevmark{\thesubsubsection\ #3}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsubsubsection*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\originalsubsubsection{#3}}
      {\originalsubsubsection[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}

% adapt \newpage so that it issues a "prev" mark, and makes \prevmark empty

\let\originalnewpage\newpage
\renewcommand{\newpage}{\markboth{prev}{\prevmark}\global\let\prevmark\empty\originalnewpage}

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \setcounter{page}{1} % when using custom titlepage

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pdfbookmark{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{tableofcontents}
  \markboth{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{}
  \tableofcontents

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pdfbookmark{Abbildungsverzeichnis}{listoffigures}
  \listoffigures

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pdfbookmark{Tabellenverzeichnis}{listoftables}
  \listoftables

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \section{This is a test section}
  \blindtext
  \subsection{This is a subsection}
  \blindtext
  \section{This is another section}


This is some text.   This is some text.   This is some text.   
This is some text.   This is some text.   This is some text.   
This is some text.   This is some text.   This is some text.   
This is some text.   This is some text.   This is some text.   

Comment out these two lines so that the next subsection starts at the top
of the page. Then the header will become that subsection title.

  \subsection{This is another subsection}
  Some more text. 

 \cleardoublepage
  \blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that will fix the main problem, but still the cases (like above shown) aren't integrated.

Comment: I don't think the mark mechanism can detect if a [sub]section starts at the top of the page. And I really can't think of any other mechanism that could do this.

Comment: I assumed that this is a hard problem. If there won't be an answer which respects the cases I will accept yours.

Comment: I have been thinking about this (even while I was sleeping) and maybe I can find a solution. But I have to find the time to work on it.

Comment: I thought that it wouldn't be possible with marks. Yet I found such a solution. Never say never!!

Comment: Thank you very much! That's nearly perfect. All pages are correct only page 4 and page 6 hold the subsection instead of the subsubsection (Basically I want the lowest section title that corresponds to the breaking text). But it's nice that page 5 is correct that was in my opinion the hardest. If that is to hard to achieve I would already accept your answer since also the subsection title is ok for me though not that fitting than the lower one. (I hope it's possible to wait for two days and give you a bounty on this answer)

Comment: OK, I didn't include subsubsections, as you did not mention these. In the usual LaTeX classes only two levels are used (chapter/section or section/subsection). But I think adding sususbsections is easy (more or less copy the others). I'll have a look into it.

Comment: Added subsubsection support.

Comment: Now page 5 is not correct anymore, but all others are fine!

Comment: What's not correct op page 5? Page 5 contains no left-over text from the previous section, so it has the first subsubsection title as header. Would you prefer 4.1? I think that's not logical.

Comment: Yes, that's the third case, and in my opinion it gives the reader the most information (atleast on a singlesided document).

Comment: Ok, I think I overlooked that requirement. But now suppose you have Section 2, followed by subsection 2.1 on a page. The next page starts with subsection 2.2. Then you want to have the Section 2 title in the header? That's difficult because normally you would have 2.1 or 2.2. And adding subsubsections makes it even harder. It would mean the system has to keep a stack of titles, rather than only the previous and the current title. I don't know if the mark system can handle that. But then I said that before and still found a way. But now I think it is much harder.

Comment: And remember, that section could have started several pages before the current page, and there could have been many subsections and subsubsections in between. And if there would be one word left over from subsection 2.1 then the 2.1 title would have to be used. If the 2.2 subsection started one line earlier, then 2.2 would be used. But if 2.2 starts at the top of the page section 2 would be used. And then you have the same thing again one lever lower. Mind boggling.

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right with this assumption. Btw I encountered a bug when using this on my 'real' text not on blindtext. Than the header line is still available, I think it belongs together with clearpage.

Comment: Well, it also may be caused by the use of `\topmark` in my solution, because that can occasionally fail. I have now changed the solution to one that doesn't need that. Can you try that? And then, I think I might have a solution for the original requirement number 3. I am working on it.